# UISearchDisplayController / UISearchResultsTableView Adding in Extra Line with Each Search ? iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController which is behaving strangely under iOS7. The first time I do a search, everything is ok and the UISearchResultsTableView displays the results correctly.

The problem is that the second time I do a search (after dismissing the table), a blank line (looks like a cell) is added to the top of the search results table :

[image]

Each subsequent search then adds in another blank line to the top of the table, and so on and so on.

Here is the code :

```
//Setup the search bar.
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 360.0f, 44.0f)];
UIBarButtonItem * searchBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
searchBar.delegate = self;
controller = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
controller.searchResultsDataSource = self;
controller.searchResultsDelegate = self;

self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[searchBarButton];

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (isLoading) {
        return;
    }

    [self filter : searchText];
    [controller.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)filter : (NSString *)text {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR number CONTAINS[cd] %@)", text, text];
    searchResults  = [standArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [searchResults count];
}

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        if ([searchResults count] ==0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        }
        else {
            NSString * name = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
            NSString * number = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number];
            NSString * resultsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", name, number];
            cell.textLabel.text = resultsString;
        }

        return cell;

    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSString * name = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
        Object * exhibitor = [self getExhibitorForStandName:standName];
        if ([exhibitor.companyName isEqualToString:standName]) {
            NSString * status = [[self getExhibitorForStandName:standName] status];
            cell.backgroundColor = [standColourMapping objectForKey:status];
        }
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not think this is the solution, but you should empty the array every time the text changes. in textDidChange you should add [searchResults removeAllObjects]; -and check this array with NSLog on second search what is the object at index 0

Comment: Under arc this would release the searchResults array at the first text change, then crash at the next.

Comment: if you do [searchResults removeAllObjects]; in textDidChange, the app crashes??

Comment: The second time you change the text yes - because searchResults has been dealloced.

Comment: removeAllObjects not dealloc the array, just empty the array. anyway NSLog on searchResults what print to the second search?

Comment: Second search is same count as first search. There are no extra items in the array.

Comment: and if you check in cellForRowAtIndexPath: the NSString resultsString, what print?

Comment: The first object in the array. There is nothing extra in the array so this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok for future travellers, this looks like a weird bug whereby the height of the UISearchBar is added to the top of the searchResultsTable each subsequent time it appears.

The solution is the following :

```
controller.searchResultsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f); //Fix for weird weird iOS7 bug where each subsequent
    //search adds the height of the searchBar to the top of the searchResultsTableView.
```

Comment: It was enough for me to set only the top inset to zero.